# How to simulate real-time after send a request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a list of songs, when I click to any of them I open the player modal then send a request to increment count view for this song, 
And at the same time, I display in the detailed song the count view, but it renders the previous last count

For example, 
This song has 30 views after I send a request it should be 31,
But it's still 30 im song details

So is there a way to make it a real-time?

Code

Just to explain
I get songs from API then pass it to manipulation function,
 then save it in the state, after user click on any song in the list I dispatch an action that's to save all list in the redux store,

Reducer

```
let initialState = {
  allSongs: [],
  currentIndex: 0,
};

const songsInPlayerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SONGS_IN_PLAYER:
      return {
        ...state,
        allSongs: action.songs,
        currentIndex: action.index,
      };


    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default songsInPlayerReducer;
```

Action

```
export const saveSongsPlayer = (songs, index) => {
  return {
    type: SONGS_IN_PLAYER,
    songs,
    index,
  };
};
```

Home screen ( get songs from API )

```
manipulateArray = async array => {
    let songs = [];
    array.map(track =>
      songs.push({
        id: track.id,
        name: track.name,
        countview: track.countview,
        url: this.state.url + track.sounds,
        img: this.state.url + track.avatar,
      }),
    );

    return songs;
  };

getRecentSongs = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await API.get('/index');

      let {recent_tracks} = response.data.data;
      let recent_songs = await this.manipulateArray(recent_tracks);


      this.setState({

        recent_songs,

        loading: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({error: true});
    }
  };


// Here a function I call after I press to any song in List 

playSong = index => {
    this.props.saveSongs(this.state.recent_songs, index);

  };
```

Music player component // I just render the count views (from redux store) and send a request to API to increment the song views

```
incremntSongView = async () => {
    const {songs, currentIndex} = this.props;
    let id = songs[currentIndex].id;
    try {
      await API.post('/increnentView', {
        id,
      });
      console.log('increment Done');
    } catch (err) {

      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  onLoad = data => {
    this.setState(
      {
        duration: Math.floor(data.duration),
        loading: false,
      },
      () => this.incremntSongView(),
    );

  }


<Text>
     {this.props.songs[this.props.currentInx].countview}
</Text>
```

Comment: You modal isn't re-rendered when the counter is inscremented. the displayed data in your modal must be a props that is udpated from your parent( local state or context), or a data directly taken from a context. By the way with some code showing how you handle datas it will be way easier to help you

Comment: Add some code. It would be easy to identify the issue.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel Can you check the question again, please?

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha Can you check the question again, please?